# Attendance tracker/multi vote

Tags: javascript

I want to create a multi vote, give people 3 options (yes/no/maybe) and log who voted and who did not vote. Is this easy to do in javascript ?  Ideally I want to not let them see anything else  on my site until they particpate in this vote, and I found code to do a one track redirect that I can modify, but I am not sure what the best way of going about the whole thing is.
I am just looking for suggestions, but any code will be great too.
My site does not support an SQL server at the moment.

Comment: What is a "multi vote"? If by "My site does not support an SQL server" you mean your site doesn't have access to _any_ database, where do you want the results logged?

Comment: i was thinking of logging into a text file. I know database's are better but I don't have one available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

index.php (first page when user enters your site)

```
session_start();
$hasVoted = $_SESSION['hasVoted'];
$vote = htmlspecialchars($_GET['vote']);

if(empty($hasVoted)){
 if(!empty($vote)){
 $_SESSION['hasVoted'] = "true";
 }
}

if($hasVoted == "true"){
header("location:home.php");
} else {
print"Please vote in next poll to access our site:";
// and here you print voting form
}
```

home.php

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['hasVoted'] !== "true"){
header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: thanks, forgot to mention that I can code a bit in JS but i  struggle with PHP, but this does help a lot !!